# Recursively create string out of array of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, iteration

Ultimately, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this, so I'm open to suggestions.

What I'm trying to do is write a recursive function that is called while iterating over each element of an array of objects. The function should take the array element, recursively iterate over its values and nested objects.

So, for example, the function might be called while iterating over an `array` of nested objects like so...

```
arrayOfNestedObjects.map(el => objectValues(el))
```

I'm using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to fetch an array of objects of this shape...

```
{
  id: 10,
  name: 'Clementina DuBuque',
  username: 'Moriah.Stanton',
  email: 'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz',
  address: {
    street: 'Kattie Turnpike',
    suite: 'Suite 198',
    city: 'Lebsackbury',
    zipcode: '31428-2261',
    geo: {
      lat: '-38.2386',
      lng: '57.2232'
    }
  },
  phone: '024-648-3804',
  website: 'ambrose.net',
  company: {
    name: 'Hoeger LLC',
    catchPhrase: 'Centralized empowering task-force',
    bs: 'target end-to-end models'
  }
}
```

What I want to return from my recursive function is a single, concatenated string of ***all*** values for each element of the array, including all values from any nested objects, like so from the above example..

```
"10clementinadubuquemoriah.stantonrey.padberg@karina.bizkattieturnpikesuite198lebsackbury31428-2261-38.238657.2232024-648-3804ambrose.nethoegerllccentralizedempoweringtask-forcetargetend-to-endmodels"
```

The problem I'm having is that there seems to be a final call of my recursive function that returns a string omitting all values from some of the nested objects. Here's what I have so far for my function...

```
function objectValues(value, ...args) {
  let string = args;
  Object.values(value).forEach((val, i) => {
    if (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null) {
      objectValues(val, string);
    } else {
      string += val
        .toString()
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .toLowerCase();
        console.log(string);
    }
  });
  return string;
}
```

Logging `string` inside of the `else` clause shows me the string I want, but logging `string` just above the `return` shows me the erroneous string missing the values from the `company` object. It must be something simple that I'm missing about how I've set up the recursion. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `...args` parameter is making things more complicated than they have to be. If `...args` is an *array*, renaming it `let string = args` is pretty confusing - especially, as you can see later, when you do `string += ...` (but `+=` doesn't make much sense on *arrays*)

Instead, just declare an empty string at the beginning of the function, concatenate it when necessary, and `return` it at the end of the function. `reduce` is a bit more appropriate than `forEach` when you're condensing an array into a single value, such as a string:

```js
const value={id:10,name:'Clementina DuBuque',username:'Moriah.Stanton',email:'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz',address:{street:'Kattie Turnpike',suite:'Suite 198',city:'Lebsackbury',zipcode:'31428-2261',geo:{lat:'-38.2386',lng:'57.2232'}},phone:'024-648-3804',website:'ambrose.net',company:{name:'Hoeger LLC',catchPhrase:'Centralized empowering task-force',bs:'target end-to-end models'}}

function objectValues(value) {
  return Object.values(value).reduce((string, val, i) => string + (
    (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null)
    ? objectValues(val)
    : val
        .toString()
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .toLowerCase()
  ));
}

console.log(objectValues(value));
```

Another option would be to exploit `JSON.stringify`'s naturally recursive nature:

```js
const value={id:10,name:'Clementina DuBuque',username:'Moriah.Stanton',email:'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz',address:{street:'Kattie Turnpike',suite:'Suite 198',city:'Lebsackbury',zipcode:'31428-2261',geo:{lat:'-38.2386',lng:'57.2232'}},phone:'024-648-3804',website:'ambrose.net',company:{name:'Hoeger LLC',catchPhrase:'Centralized empowering task-force',bs:'target end-to-end models'}}

function objectValues(value) {
  let string = '';
  JSON.stringify(value, (_, val) => {
    if (typeof val === 'string') string += val.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
    return val;
  });
  return string;
}

console.log(objectValues(value));
```

Comment: `string += objectValues(val, string);` should just be `string += objectValues(val);` right?

Comment: Oh, yep, no need for that argument anymore

Comment: Oh, sorry! I attached the wrong `console.log()` statement. I definitely want _all_ values out of the outer object and any nested objects. And for `...args`, I was trying to pass `string` back into the function, not any arrays. The function will be called inside of an array iteration method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @joehodd - There is no need to pass an accumulator string back into the function to achieve what you are asking for in the question. You should probably keep this function clean and do the concatenation in the array iterator.

Comment: @joehodd If you added the wrong info in your question, you should edit your question to include the right info instead.

Comment: @JasonB Sorry for that! I edited my question for both accuracy and clarity. Thanks for the suggestion. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks for your help! I guess my question was unclear, so I edited it for clarity and accuracy if you want to look. But I really like your final answer. Thanks for the hint on using `reduce`. I was so focused on just doing the recursion correctly I didn't think of switching out `forEach` for that. Awesome stuff, really! What made it click for me was concatenating `string` with _either_ the recursive call of `objectValues` _or_ `val` itself. Dumb mistake, really.

Comment: @joehdodd Mapping each object to a string works just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/o4dbtuaL/

Comment: @CertainPerformance, oh very cool! Another good option. Thanks for all your help.